# finding the language stem of vowelless Hebrew

Tags: morphology, computational-linguistics, hebrew, tools

I am looking for tools to find the language stem in **vowelless Hebrew**, preferably a full list of suffixes and prefixes with the stem.

A small list can be found on wikipedia.
An extensive list can be found on mila.

A full list of rules and rulesets that can be programmed preferably.
I want to re-code and integrate this code myself, so a Exe or on-line tool does not help. I can read PHP, MS Basic, Python, C or similar languages.
With this tool i want to analyse Hebrew vowelless text.

However, while still studying the basics of the Hebrew (vowelless!) grammar, i've seen that letters will dissolve when the basic stem of verbs is bended into narrative or perfective form. Then, some verbs do not have a stem of 2 or 3 letters anymore, but are left with a stem of only 1 original letter.

Such anomalies make it very difficult to program, and for that, **I am primary looking for an existing set of rules on the prefix and suffix.**

If I have that, the remainder is some sort of stem, which could be matched with an extensive database such as the Mila database. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: why did this question get a -1 vote ?

Answer (score 1):

In Computational linguistics, there are tools called "Stemmer" or "Lemmatizer" that perform the task you are asking for. Entering "hebrew lemmatizer" into duckduckgo search reveals the following first hit

http://code972.com/blog/2013/08/129-hebrew-search-with-elasticsearch-and-hebmorph

with a reference to GitHub

https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph

Check this out!

Comment: Also, those links you mention are a bit too much code for the task i wish to perform. 
Now i will use the prefix-afix-suffix that i have and write a tool myself first probably in Excel.